# Recreate graph gradient colors in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm looking to create very high quality data visualization in R and I'm not sure how to create some of the gradient colors in the in the bar graph below (full link [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/1423171-Some-Analytics/attachments/208613)).

I believe ggplot can do some gradient fills, but in this case, i'd need a stacked color and background color, both of a light grey-to-orange gradient. I can't find a command to do that. The column widths would have to be full and a dark grey border. (i don't need the symbols).

What ggplot (or other) command could replicate this design? Thanks for any direction. Really hoping I can recreate some of my favorite designs in R.

[image: bar graph]

Comment: you can use geom_bar to plot the original barplot, then use geom_rect to add a rectangle above each bar(rather than using a stacked bar). Then use alpha transparency to highlight the bar you want.

Comment: Here's how to create gradient backgrounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136725/ggplot2-plot-background-colour-gradient, and here's how to create border colors: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html. All in all, I'd say R is perhaps not made to create "very high quality data visualization" [sic]. You may wanna use PowerPoint or Inkscape instead. There, it's also easy to create shadows and other things.