# Human color spectrum for plot background

Tags: r, graphics, colors, gradient

I'm trying to make an image similar to this one by OpenWetWare ([source](https://openwetware.org/wiki/BIO254:Phototransduction)). I generate the curves using the [colourvision package.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colourvision/) I made the color spectrum with the `rainbow()` palette, based on code by @baptiste found [here](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/plot-background-excel-gradient-style-background-td4632138.html#a4634954) (and repeated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136725/plot-background-colour-in-gradient)).

[image]

**Problem and question**
The gradient I produced does not correspond to the actual color frequencies. How can I generate a spectrum that coincides (at least closely) with the actual color frequencies (e.g., 550 nm in green-yellow territory, not cyan). I'm certain `rainbow()` is probably not the way to generate the needed palette but I do not know what would be the best way.

**MWE**

```
library(colourvision)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

gradient <- t(rev(rainbow(20))) # higher value for smoother gradient
g <- rasterGrob(gradient, width = unit(1, "npc"), height = unit(1, "npc"), interpolate = TRUE) 

human <- photor(lambda.max = c(420, 530, 560), lambda = seq(400, 700, 1))

ggplot(data = human, aes(x = Wavelength)) +
  annotation_custom(g, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
  geom_line(aes(y = lambda.max420), color = "white") +
  geom_line(aes(y = lambda.max530), color = "white") +
  geom_line(aes(y = lambda.max560), color = "white") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(400, 700, 50)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) # Save space for question
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `w_length2rgb` in the `photobiology` package.

Comment: In general: it is better to avoid using colour in such figures: it gives a wrong idea on colours. Remember that one colour could be seen as an other, depending eye adaptation. See the 'note' of their master when his saw colours, as copied and explained in Giorgianni & Madden

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi In general, I agree. I need it for a specific purpose, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `w_length2rgb` from the `photobiology` package:

```
library(photobiology)

gradient <- t(w_length2rgb(400:700))

#then the rest of your code as it is
```

[image]

Following your comment, and just for completeness, you could also use the data from `cvrl.org`, which I think looks better...

```
conesdata <- read.csv("http://www.cvrl.org/database/data/cones/linss10e_5.csv")
names(conesdata) <- c("Wavelength", "Red", "Green", "Blue")
conesdata[is.na(conesdata)] <- 0
conesdata$colour <- rgb(conesdata$Red, conesdata$Green, conesdata$Blue)   
gradient <- t(conesdata$colour[conesdata$Wavelength >= 400 & conesdata$Wavelength <= 700])

#then the rest of your code as before
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution got me close. I played with the chromaticity model and the color range to get very close so that the rightmost peak is actually in yellow, like the original. It would be great if the left end of the spectrum included "violet" colors but it seems `w_length2rgb` is simulating the spectrum visible to humans and so fades to black. Do you know of a way to generate the broader spectrum? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know of any other standard packages to do this, although, if you know the expected wavelength-colour values at a few points it would not be too difficult to write a function to stretch a spectrum produced with `rainbow` - perhaps using the `approx` function to interpolate.

Comment: I got very close to my desired result using data from http://www.cvrl.org/cones.htm instead of `colourvision` to make the curves, in combination with your solution.

Comment: @MichaelSTaylor Great! For completeness, I have updated the answer with a version based on the colour data from cvrl.org.  Not entirely sure whether I have used the right dataset, but it produces a nicer gradient!

Comment: The new gradient is much nicer. You did you the same dataset I chose. Thank you!